# How to fix Electron Python Eel error when compiling to an exe using '--onefile' PyInstaller

Tags: javascript, python, electron, eel

I am trying to experiment with GUIs in Python, and since I like web development I found eel which allows the use of HTML, CSS and JS in Python GUIs. However, I noticed that it relies on certain browsers being installed, but had an option for electron. I installed electron with `npm install electron` and used the example electron template provided at [the official Github repo](https://github.com/python-eel/Eel/blob/main/examples/09%20-%20Eelectron-quick-start/main.js) modified it a bit to support my need.
Project Structure:

```
chatApp/
|--node_modules/
|--web/
|  |--home/
|  |  |--index.html
|  |--include/
|  |  |--css/
|  |  |  |--style.css
|  |  |--js/
|  |  |  |--main.js
|  |--index.html
|--app.py
|--index.js
```

The PyInstaller command:

```
pyinstaller app.py --hidden-import bottle_websocket --add-data "C:\Users\coder\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\eel\eel.js;eel" --add-data "web;web" --add-data "node_modules;node_modules" --add-data "index.js;index" --onefile --noconsole
```

app.py:

```py
# Allow for --noconsole
import sys, io

buffer = io.StringIO()
sys.stdout = sys.stderr = buffer

# Main Code
import eel

SERVERS = {
    "general": {"users": [], "messages": {}},
}

eel.init("web")

@eel.expose
def join_server(server_name):
    if server_name not in SERVERS:
        SERVERS[server_name] = {"users": [], "messages": {}}
    SERVERS[server_name]["users"].append(eel.get_user()())

# eel.start('/home/index.html', mode='custom', cmdline_args=["./node_modules/electron/dist/electron.exe", "./index.js"]) # For Testing
eel.start("/home/index.html", mode="custom", cmdline_args=["./node_modules/electron/dist/electron.exe", "./index/index.js"]) # For build
```

index.js

```js
// Modules to control application life and create native browser window
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')

// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
let mainWindow

function createWindow () {
    // Create the browser window.
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true
        }
    })
    // Remove the menu bar
    mainWindow.removeMenu();
    // and load the index.html of the app.
    mainWindow.loadURL('http://localhost:8000/index.html');

    // Open the DevTools.
    // mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()

    // Emitted when the window is closed.
    mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
        // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
        // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
        // when you should delete the corresponding element.
        mainWindow = null
        app.quit();
    })
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', createWindow)

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
    // On macOS it is common for applications and their menu bar
    // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit()
})

app.on('activate', function () {
    // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
    // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
    if (mainWindow === null) createWindow()
})

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and require them here.
```

Here is the error it gives:
[File Not Found Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcjwW.png)

Yet it works just fine with the PyInstaller command without the `--onefile`:

```
pyinstaller app.py --hidden-import bottle_websocket --add-data "C:\Users\coder\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\eel\eel.js;eel" --add-data "web;web" --add-data "node_modules;node_modules" --add-data "index.js;index" --noconsole
```

It results in this:
[Working Electron App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1a9i.png)

I have tried replacing the `./` with `/` and nothing as well as changed all the `/` with `\\` in `cmdline_args=["./node_modules/electron/dist/electron.exe", "./index/index.js"]`. I can't think of anything else to try and fix the error as it says that the file cannot be found which I would assume means that the path is incorrect.